# setTimeout(func, 0) の仕様

Tags: javascript

[lodashのdefer](https://lodash.com/docs#defer)の説明を見ると、以下のように書いてあります。

> Defers invoking the func until the current call stack has cleared.

私は、同じ目的で次のようなコードを書くことがあります。

```
setTimeout(function () {
    /* 今の一連の処理が完了するまで遅延させたい処理 */
}, 0);
```

これと同じだろうと思ってlodashのコードを見てみると、第二引数には`1`を渡していました。
なぜ`0`ではなくあえて`1`を指定するのでしょうか？
もしかすると、`0`では遅延させられない（現在実行中の処理をブロックして実行してしまう）可能性がありますか？

Comment: 一般に最小のインターバルが4msですので、事実上違いはありません。[参考](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341803/difference-between-settimeoutfn-0-and-settimeoutfn-1)

Comment: 参考リンクの回答のコメントにも書かれていますが、正しくは`If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then increase timeout to 4.`です。`timeout`の初期値は0ms(省略可)で、その場合は次のタイマータスク発火時に実行されます。(ただし実行順はタスクのキューの状態に依存) [EventLoop#Zero_delays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Zero_delays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> なぜ0ではなくあえて1を指定するのでしょうか？

lodashやUnderscore.jsの`defer`で`setTimeout(func, 0)`ではなく1msが指定されている理由は、古いChromeでUIスレッドがブロックされることがあるからのようです(?)。

https://github.com/lodash/lodash/pull/1334#issuecomment-120736265

> We avoid a setTimeout of 0 because I believe old Chrome could end up blocking the UI thread with them.

---

`setTimeout(func, 0)`について

7.4. Timers
http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#timers

`timeout`の初期値は0msで省略可能です。

ただし、タイマーの`nesting level`が5より大きく`timeout`が4msより小さい場合、`timeout`は4msに設定されます。

> NOTE:
>   Timers can be nested; after five such nested timers, however, the interval is forced to be at least four milliseconds.

> 8. If nesting level is greater than 5, and timeout is less than 4, then increase timeout to 4.

---

0ms(初期値)の場合、`scheduled to run at the next opportunity`ですが、いつ実行されるかはタスクに積まれているキューの状態に依存します。

EXAMPLE 11
http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#example-8b53adfc

```
function rescheduleWork() {
var handle = setTimeout(rescheduleWork, 0); // preschedule next iteration
if (doExpensiveWork())
  clearTimeout(handle); // clear the timeout if we don’t need it
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Notes

> Because even though setTimeout was called with a delay of zero, it's placed on a queue and scheduled to run at the next opportunity, not immediately.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop#Zero_delays

> Zero delay doesn't actually mean the call back will fire-off after zero milliseconds. Calling setTimeout with a delay of 0 (zero) milliseconds doesn't execute the callback function after the given interval. The execution depends on the number of awaiting tasks in the queue.

```js
(function () {

  console.log('this is the start');

  setTimeout(function cb() {
    console.log('this is a msg from call back');
  });

  console.log('this is just a message');

  setTimeout(function cb1() {
    console.log('this is a msg from call back1');
  }, 0);

  console.log('this is the  end');

})();
```